# redirecting HTTPS requests to http in lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd

I have a lighttpd server running which has an SSL certificate installed. I would, due to certain reasons, like to forward all https: //www. requests to http: //www.

My lighttpd code looks like as follows:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443"
{
   ssl.engine = "enable"
   ssl.pemfile = "/path/to/pem/file"
   ssl.ca-file = "/path/to/ca/file"
   HTTP["host"] =~ "^www\.(.*)$" {
       url.redirect = ("^/(.*)" => "http://www.%1$1")
   }
}
```

Can you please point out the problem here. Another thing, what is the difference between %1 and $1 ?

Comment: Hi would you mind giving a bit more detail on what your are trying to achieve? User => URL:https://www.example.com => redirect to => http://www.example.com. Why? What site or URL needs to be secured? Thanks,

Comment: Hi Danie, I'd like to redirect https: //www.example.com to http: //www.example.com

Comment: @chochim but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this one:

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "https" {
        $HTTP["host"] =~ "example.com" {
                url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://www.example.com/$1" )
        }
}
```

But be careful, some browser keep in mind that a website use `https`. So it will always try to access the `https` version no matter the redirect that send the webserver. I have tried this case and Firefox / Chrome told me that my website goes into an infite redirect loop. But when I curl my website on `https`, I got a 301 to `http`. And on `http` a 200.

So it's hard to test ...

For your second question, it's [in the doc](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_modredirect):

> Note that the "%1" in the url.redirect target refers to the parenthesized subexpression in the conditional regexp (.*). It does not necessarily have the meaning that "%1" would have in evhost.path-pattern (where it would mean 'top-level domain'). If url.redirect is specified within a regex conditional, % patterns are replaced by the corresponding groups from the condition regex. %1 is replaced with the first subexpression, %2 with the second, etc. %0 is replaced by the entire substring matching the regexp. See above and below for examples using % patterns.